# how to detect a real front end issue?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application, defect-tracking, application-software-testing

If I am testing a website, perform a "zoom in" action, and notice that the features are no longer in their correct places (the boundaries have changed), should I consider this behavior a software issue?

Please refer to the two images below(before and after zoom).

[image: Before zooming in]
[image: After zooming in]

Comment: Are you testing on a desktop (browser) or a phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In software testing company different types of testing is performed by quality assurance engineers. In this case, if the application is responsive then position should not be changed and you can file a bug for this. On the other side, if the application is non-responsive then you can clarify the behavior of this issue from developer without filing a bug as it may be considered 'Not a bug' later.

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I consider this behavior as a SW issue?

I should say so. You might even consider it a usability or accessibility issue. If something happens against what you expect you should file a bug. It can always be closed after investigation.